# Can I use css-grid to display an unknown number of items, in left-to-right reading order, over two rows?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'd like to display a number of divs in left-to-right order, giving them an equal amount of space and spreading them over two rows.

e.g.

[div 1] | [div 2] | [div 3]
[div 4] | [div 5] | [div 6]

or

[div 1] | [div 2] | [div 3] | [div 4]
[div 5] | [div 6] | [div 7] | [div 8]

What's important is that I don't know how many elements there will be. If it's six, then I'll need three columns. If it's eight, then I'll need four columns. And so on.

If I give the grid container the following attributes:

```
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
```

Then my elements are given the right amount of space, but are displayed in the wrong order.

[div 1] | [div 3] | [div 5] | [div 7]
[div 2] | [div 4] | [div 6] | [div 8]

If I give the grid container the following attributes instead:

```
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
```

Then the elements appear in a single column.

[div 1]
[div 2]
...

Is there a simple way to display my elements across 2 rows, while maintaining left-to-right reading order, if I don't know how many elements there will be?

Comment: If you don't know the number of items then CSS-Grid can't help you without Javascript to determine the number of columns.

Comment: Fair enough. If it can't be done without a bit of Javascript, then at least I know that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A CSS only solution where you need to write a bit of CSS to cover many cases. The below code covers up to 12 elements and the CSS isn't that big. You can keep adding more to cover more cases.

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow:columns;
  grid-auto-columns:1fr;
  counter-reset: divs;
  margin: 5px;
  border:1px solid;
}

.box div  {
  border:1px solid red;
}

.box div:before {
  counter-increment: divs;
  content: counter(divs);
}

.box div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(3) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(4) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(4):nth-last-child(5) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(5):nth-last-child(6) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(6):nth-last-child(7) ~ *
/*
.box div:nth-child(N):nth-last-child(N+1) ~ * 
*/{
   grid-row:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>


<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
</div>
```

A SASS code to generate the CSS (you can try here: https://www.sassmeister.com/)

```
$n:12; /* make this a big as you need */

@for $i from 1 through $n {
  .box div:nth-child(#{$i}):nth-last-child(#{$i + 1}) ~ *{grid-row:2}
}
```

---

You can also cover odd number of elements:

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow:columns;
  grid-auto-columns:1fr;
  counter-reset: divs;
  margin: 5px;
  border:1px solid;
}

.box div  {
  border:1px solid red;
   grid-row:1;
}

.box div:before {
  counter-increment: divs;
  content: counter(divs);
}

.box div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(2) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(3) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(3) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(4) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(4):nth-last-child(4) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(4):nth-last-child(5) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(5):nth-last-child(5) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(5):nth-last-child(6) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(6):nth-last-child(6) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(6):nth-last-child(7) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(7):nth-last-child(7) ~ *{
   grid-row:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
</div>
```

The SASS code:

```
$n:12;

@for $i from 1 through $n {
  .box div:nth-child(#{$i}):nth-last-child(#{$i + 1}) ~ *,
  .box div:nth-child(#{$i + 1}):nth-last-child(#{$i + 1}) ~ *{grid-row:2}
}
```

Comment: Do you know - this is actually perfect for my use case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You will need javascript to calculate a min-width value for the grid column , then auto-fit,mimax() can do.

possible example

```js
let yop =document.querySelectorAll('#test  div')
document.body.style.setProperty('--minWidth', Math.ceil(200 / yop.length) -1 +'%' );
```

```css
#test {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(var(--minWidth), 1fr));
  counter-reset: divs;
  /* width:800px; or not */
}

div div  {
  border: solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

div div:before {
  counter-increment: divs;
  content: counter(divs);
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
</div>
```

Its a basic approach , a percentage calculated from 200 willdraw 2 rows, 300 will draw 3 rows and so on.

But it can be a flex layout or floatting element, grid is not the magic here. CSS is unable to read the dom and adapt a value on the fly like you would wish.