# CSS Grid Responsive layout keeping complete rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I have a grid layout for a dashboard I am building. I am trying to achieve the following:

- Maintain aspect ratio of grid elements
- Ensure each grid row is filled/complete. This is the problem child in my case. I have seen multiple tutorials and answers on here where the rows may contain a leftover element in a new row as the width decreases. This creates a lot of empty space in the grid to the right of the isolated grid elements/incomplete row. I want the grid to shift to decrease columns to the next lowest divisible number result in complete rows. If the grid starts with a non divisible number (prime) it can only go to a single column for collapsing say 3 grid items collapses to 1 since its the highest divisor hence maintaining complete rows. Another example, 6 items would collapse to 3 columns of 2 then 2 columns of 3 then 1 column of 6.

I am curious if there is a pure CSS method for ensuring the row stays complete or if this will require javascript. Either answer will suffice but I will favor a pure css solution.

My code so far:

```css
.grid-4-2-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "grid-child-1 grid-child-2 grid-child-3 grid-child-4";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.grid-child {
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.grid-child .grid-content {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .grid-4-2-1 {
    grid-template-areas: "grid-child-1 grid-child-2 grid-child-3 grid-child-4";
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
  }
}


/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {}
```

```html
<div class="grid-4-2-1">
  <grid-child-1 class="grid-child">
    <div class="grid-content">Overview</div>
  </grid-child-1>
  <grid-child-2 class="grid-child">
    <div class="grid-content">Overview</div>
  </grid-child-2>
  <grid-child-3 class="grid-child">
    <div class="grid-content">Overview</div>
  </grid-child-3>
  <grid-child-4 class="grid-child">
    <div class="grid-content">Overview</div>
  </grid-child-4>
</div>
```

Comment: I tihnk this is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65245005/8620333 no?

Answer (score 1):

You could use pure CSS to create a grid system by using the display grid and display grid-auto-columns attriubutes. link for more reference (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-auto-columns.asp)

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow:columns;
  grid-auto-columns:1fr;
  counter-reset: divs;
  margin: 10px;
  border:1px solid;
}

.box div  {
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.box div:before {
  counter-increment: divs;
  content: counter(divs);
}

.box div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(3) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(4) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(4):nth-last-child(5) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(5):nth-last-child(6) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(6):nth-last-child(7) ~ *

{
   grid-row:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>  
  <div></div>

</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>


<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
</div>
```