# CSS Grid split evenly with a spacer

Tags: css, css-grid

I was wondering if it would be possible to split a `grid` evenly. For instance, say a `ul` has 6 `li` - the grid would take `6/2` and insert a spacer in the middle of free space. Here is a design:
[image]

I do not want to use Javascript or `column-count` + `float` to accomplish this. I was just wondering if this was easily implemented. I am working with WordPress and I'd like to avoid having to make a left and right menu.

Comment: Only if the number of items is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will consider a similar idea used in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65245005/8620333) where you can define a CSS for each case to cover all the possibilities (considering that you will have a max boundary)

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  counter-reset: divs;
  margin: 5px;
  border:1px solid;
}

.box div  {
  border:1px solid red;
  width:50px;
}

.box div:before {
  counter-increment: divs;
  content: counter(divs);
}

.box div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2) + *,
.box div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(3) + *,
.box div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(4) + *,
.box div:nth-child(4):nth-last-child(5) + *,
.box div:nth-child(5):nth-last-child(6) + *,
.box div:nth-child(6):nth-last-child(7) + *
/*
.box div:nth-child(N):nth-last-child(N+1) + * 
*/{
   margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div>
</div>


<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div> 
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div> 
</div>
```

A SASS code to generate the above CSS

```
$n:12; /* make this a big as you need */

@for $i from 1 through $n {
  .box div:nth-child(#{$i}):nth-last-child(#{$i + 1}) + *{margin-left:auto}
}
```

Another kind of configuration:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  counter-reset: divs;
  margin: 5px;
  border:1px solid;
}
.box::after {
  content:"";
  min-width:50px; /* your spacer here */
}

.box div  {
  border:1px solid red;
  flex:1;
}

.box div:before {
  counter-increment: divs;
  content: counter(divs);
}

.box div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(3) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(4) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(4):nth-last-child(5) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(5):nth-last-child(6) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(6):nth-last-child(7) ~ *
/*
.box div:nth-child(N):nth-last-child(N+1) ~ * 
*/{
   order:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div>
</div>


<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div> 
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div> 
</div>
```

You can play with the alignment like you want:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  counter-reset: divs;
  margin: 5px;
  border:1px solid;
}
.box::after {
  content:"";
  min-width:50px; /* your spacer here */
}

.box div  {
  border:1px solid red;
  width:50px;
  margin:auto;
}

.box div:before {
  counter-increment: divs;
  content: counter(divs);
}

.box div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(3) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(4) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(4):nth-last-child(5) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(5):nth-last-child(6) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(6):nth-last-child(7) ~ *
/*
.box div:nth-child(N):nth-last-child(N+1) ~ * 
*/{
   order:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div>
</div>


<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div> 
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div> 
</div>
```

---

CSS grid can also do it:

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow:column;
  grid-auto-columns:1fr;
  counter-reset: divs;
  margin: 5px;
  border:1px solid;
}
.box::after {
  content:"";
}

.box div  {
  border:1px solid red;
}

.box div:before {
  counter-increment: divs;
  content: counter(divs);
}

.box div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(3) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(4) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(4):nth-last-child(5) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(5):nth-last-child(6) ~ *,
.box div:nth-child(6):nth-last-child(7) ~ *
/*
.box div:nth-child(N):nth-last-child(N+1) ~ * 
*/{
   order:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div>
</div>


<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div> 
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div> 
</div>
```