# CSS Grid make the column gap identical

Tags: css

How do I make the gap/space between items to be the same?

I've tried `grid-column-gap` but the gap will be different since the number of items on each row are different, where the first and third row is bigger and the second row is the ideal gap space.

Another option is to make the width of the items to be 100% and add a margin but this way their width will be different as items on the second row will be smaller.

What I wanna achieve is:

1. Center all of the items in the div `#innerContainer`
2. Make the gap between items to be the same
3. The width of each item is the same

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#innerContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(60, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 9px;
  grid-row-gap: 9px;
}

.item {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column: auto / span 15;
}

.item:nth-child(4)~.item {
  grid-column: auto / span 12
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="innerContainer">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Must it be on two lines or can it just break onto a thrid line? Meaning: Does every row have to have its own number of items or it is always say 4 items per row?

Comment: It must be three lines, and the numbers on each row are defined/fixed. First row: 4 items; Second row: 5 items; Third row: 4 items;

Comment: @RodneyWeber Maibe [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65240397/can-i-use-css-grid-to-display-an-unknown-number-of-items-in-left-to-right-readi) will you help.

Comment: @ЖнецЪ Thanks for the reference but I think it's different because his question is "unknown number of items over two rows" as well as left to right. In my question, the number of items on each row is defined and it's center instead from left to right.

Comment: @RodneyWeber Please have a look at my solution. It might just be what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox now offers a `gap` property. We could use that along with multiple rows of content to make it work.

You should use flexbox for the flexible-sizing. It is because grid is meant to be table-like. And it does not really want to have you mess around with the spaces too much. It is always aligned to some raster.

It should work accross all major browsers (see: https://caniuse.com/?search=gap) but you could always fallback to using paddings instead or space the items evenly and make the rows wide enough so that the available space is equal to the `n * n_size + (n-1) * gap`.

```css
#container {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  /* just for visuals */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#innerContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="innerContainer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop CSS grid and use flexbox:

```css
#innerContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  gap: 4.5px 9px;
}
/* pseudo element will seperate your elements*/
#innerContainer:before,
#innerContainer:after {
  content:"";
  flex-basis:100%
}
#innerContainer:after {
  order:2;
}
/**/
/* 4 items before the "before" */
.item:nth-child(-n + 4) {
  order:-1;
}
/* 4 items after the "after" */
.item:nth-last-child(-n + 4) {
  order:3;
}

.item {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="innerContainer">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Personally, I don't like the general idea of having to build these "hacky" solutions. You do actually something that is semantically not really there and it depends on the count of items. I feel like the design should follow the semantic. Then again, it is not your fault. If these are the requirements and it is just a stream of `<div class="item">` then it is a clever solution nonetheless and it works.