# CSS distribute items evenly accross two rows while keeping the width of the items flexible

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to create the following design:
[image]

The html looks similar to this

```
<div className='container'>
  <div className='badge'/>
  <div className='badge'/>
  <div className='badge'/>
  <div className='badge'/>
  <div className='badge'/>
  <div className='badge'/>
  <div className='badge'/>
  <div className='badge'/>
</div>
```

The badges should be evenly spread accross two rows, so if there are 8 badges in total like in the example every row should contain four badges. However, there can also be less badges in some cases, e.g. if there are six badges each row should contain 3 badges. Additionally the width of the badges needs to be flexible while the margin between items should always stay the same. I tried achieving this with flexbox and with grid as well without success. Is it even possible to achieve something like this with just CSS or would I have to divide the array of items using code and wrap them in two divs?

Comment: Not possible with CSS. You need javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

`grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);` to specify that you want 2 rows. Feel free to replace `auto` with any size you want.

`grid-auto-flow: column;` tells the auto-placement algorithm to fill in each column in turn.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='badge'>Here 1</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here 2</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here 3</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here 4</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here 5</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here 6</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here 7</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here 8</div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='badge'>Here 1</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here 2</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here 3</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here 4</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here 5</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here 6</div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='badge'>Here 1</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here 2</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here 3</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here 4</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here 5</div>
</div>
```

If the way elements are distributed is a problem for you, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65245005/16688813). (covers up to 12 elements)

Comment: This is one of the approaches I considered as well but as you can see in the screenshot, the widths of the badges differ which I don't think is possible to handle with a CSS grid. I'll update the question to make it more clear that the width of the divs needs to be flexible

Answer (score -2):

You can change the `flex-basis: 25%;` in your case

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.badge {
  padding: 5px 2.5%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='badge'>Here</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here</div>
  <div class='badge'>Here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not going to work as the divs will then have a fixed width and won't be sized according to the content itself